# Cloudformation: Dynamic Reference with Parameter

Tags: aws-cloudformation

Is it possible to include a parameter or export from another stack within a Secrets Manager Dynamic reference? The code shown below works if I used the fixed Secrets MAnager reference but I need to include a parameter or export form another stack in the secrets path.

Have tried a Join.

```
    "RDSCluster": {
        "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBCluster",
        "DeletionPolicy": "Delete",
        "Properties": {
            "MasterUsername": "admin",
            "Engine": "aurora-mysql",
            "MasterUserPassword": "{{resolve:secretsmanager:xxxx/App/DBPassword:SecretString:MYSQL_PASSWORD}}",
```

## Line above with fixed SecretsManager reference works

```
            "MasterUserPassword": "{{resolve:secretsmanager:$InputParameter/App/DBPassword:SecretString:MYSQL_PASSWORD}}"
```

## Line above does not work

Comment: If this is standard cloudformation, then no it won't work, because that's not how you reference parameters. You need to use "Fn::Sub" to substitute something in a string with your parameter value. I write templates in YAML so don't know the JSON version off the top of my head, but in YAML you'd do something like `MasterUserPassword: !Sub {{resolve:secretsmanager:${InputParameter}/App/DBPassword:SecretString:MYSQL_PASSWORD}}`

Comment: @404 Thank you for this information, if I could mark the comment above as the answer I would.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither direct referencing or replace works. The comment from 404 above is correct but I cannot mark it as the answer. An example using 2 parameters with a Secrets Manager dynamic reference is shown below.

```
                "MasterUserPassword": {
                    "Fn::Sub": ["{{resolve:secretsmanager:${Parameter1Replace}-${Parameter2Replace}/DBPassword:SecretString:MYSQL_PASSWORD}}", {
                            "Parameter1Replace": {
                                "Ref": "Parameter1"
                            },
                            "Parameter2Replace": {
                                "Ref": "Parameter2"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
```

Comment: I just checked it and simplified version by 404 works

Answer (score 0):

So, when you have several variables and text that you want to put together like that, it's best to separate them and join them that way they can each be resolved on their own and put together in a cohesive format.

Now, since I don't know EXACTLY what everything is doing, I'll take a shot and say you need to put this together in a format similar to this:

```
MasterUserPassword: !Join ['',['{{resolve:secretsmanager',':','$InputParameter','/App/DBPassword:','SecretString',':','MYSQL_PASSWORD','}}']]
```

I doubt what I wrote above will work 'as-is' but hopefully it will get you closer to what you are looking for.